# I want run this code for multiple pages these code will scrape only 1 page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want run this code for multiple pages these code will scrape only 1 page resolve these issue I a very thankful to you I tried but they do not scrape multiple pages they run but scrape 1 page

```
import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    baseurl='https://www.tradesupply.eu'
    headers ={
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
    }
    for page in range(0, 10):
         r=requests.get('https://www.tradesupply.eu/categories.html?name=drum&type=simple={page}'.format(page=page), headers = headers) 
         soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
         tra = soup.find_all('li',class_='products__item')
         productlinks=[]
         Title=[]
         Brand=[]
         Colour=[]
         Printer=[]
         Code=[]
         Des=[]
    for links in tra:
        for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
            comp=baseurl+link['href']
            productlinks.append(comp)
    
    for link in productlinks:
        r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        title=soup.find('h1').text
        Title.append(title)
        brand=soup.find('div',class_="product__brand").text
        Brand.append(brand)
        colour=soup.find('div',class_="product__colour").text 
        Colour.append(colour)
        printer=soup.find('div',class_="product__printer-manufacturer").text
        Printer.append(printer)
        code=soup.find('div',class_='l-product__codeblock').text.strip()
        Code.append(code)
        des=soup.find('div',class_="padding").text.strip()
        Des.append(des)
        
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        
        {"Title": Title, "brand": Brand,"colour":Colour,"printer":Printer,"code":Code,"des":Des}
    )
    print(df)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `for loops` are correctly indented?

Comment: yes for loop are properly indented

Comment: They are not. Don't you see you loop over the ten pages and then you exit the loop before looping again in the `tra` list? Meaning that you loop over the last `tra` only, not over all ten of those. I suggest you to get some more experience with the basics of python before getting involved in more complex projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few fixes in your code will get you what you want. Mostly indentations.

- You are creating the lists (Title, Brand, Colour, Printer etc,) and appending entries to  for every page. So effectively only the last pages items will be present in these lists.
- When you extract data from using the last two `for-loops`, you only get the last page's items. So the dataframe shows only those.

Here are few fixes I made to make your code work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl='https://www.tradesupply.eu'
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
productlinks=[]
Title=[]
Brand=[]
Colour=[]
Printer=[]
Code=[]
Des=[]

for page in range(0, 10):
    url = 'https://www.tradesupply.eu/categories.html?name=drum&type=simple={page}'.format(page=page)
    r=requests.get(url, headers = headers) 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    tra = soup.find_all('li',class_='products__item')
     
    for links in tra:
        for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
            comp=baseurl+link['href']
            productlinks.append(comp)


for link in productlinks:
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    title=soup.find('h1').text
    Title.append(title)
    brand=soup.find('div',class_="product__brand").text
    Brand.append(brand)
    colour=soup.find('div',class_="product__colour").text 
    Colour.append(colour)
    printer=soup.find('div',class_="product__printer-manufacturer").text
    Printer.append(printer)
    code=soup.find('div',class_='l-product__codeblock').text.strip()
    Code.append(code)
    des=soup.find('div',class_="padding").text.strip()
    Des.append(des)
    

df = pd.DataFrame(
    
    {"Title": Title, "brand": Brand,"colour":Colour,"printer":Printer,"code":Code,"des":Des}
)
print(df)
```

```
                                                 Title  ...                                                des
0           Compatible HP CF219A Drum 12000 Page Yield  ...  Compatible replacement for HP CF219A. Page Yie...
1      Compatible Brother DR2400 Drum 12000 Page Yield  ...  Compatible replacement for Brother DR-2400. Pa...
2    Compatible Brother DR2300  Drum  12000 Page Yield  ...  Compatible replacement for Brother DR2300. Pag...
3      Compatible Brother DR3300 Drum 30000 Page Yield  ...  Compatible replacement for Brother DR3300. Pag...
4    Compatible Brother DR3200 / DR3100 Universal D...  ...  Compatible replacement for Brother DR3200. Pag...
..                                                 ...  ...                                                ...
115  Compatible Xerox Drum 101R00474 3260 3215 3225...  ...                                                   
116  Compatible Brother DR243CLBK Black Drum 18000 ...  ...  Compatible replacement for  . Page Yield or Vo...
117  Compatible Brother DR243CLM Magenta Drum  1800...  ...  Compatible replacement for  . Page Yield or Vo...
118   Compatible Xerox 101R00555 Drum 30000 Page Yield  ...                                                   
119    Compatible Brother DR2200 Drum 12000 Page Yield  ...  Compatible replacement for Brother DR2200. Pag...

[120 rows x 6 columns]
```